# Is there any need for both [finite-state-machine] and [state-machine]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Both [finite-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) and [state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-machine) have their own synonyms, but aren't they also synonyms of each other? It's not like [state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-machine) allows for infinite state-machines (it even explicitly says "finite" in the tag description). Without delving deep into the tags, it appears that these are both the same. Who can be an "expert" in one without being an "expert" in the other?

I believe [finite-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) should be merged into [state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-machine). Not the other direction, since there are ~600 [state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-machine) questions but only ~200 [finite-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) questions.

Comment: *"It's not like state-machines allows for infinite state-machines"* - What about Read-only Turning Machines?