# Synonyms for "finite-state-machine" tags

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

For posts involving finite-state-machine, there are three associated tags, namely the [**fsm**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fsm) tag, the **[finite-state-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/finite-state-machine/info)**, tag, the [**finite-automata**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/finite-automata) tag. The tag [**state-machines**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/state-machines) is also a candidate, as discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306302/is-there-any-need-for-both-finite-state-machine-and-state-machines).

Only the **fsm** tag has a substantial tag wiki, also the **finite-state-machine** tag lists **fsm** as its synonym. Out of the three, **finite-automata** has the most associated posts, followed by **fsm**, and then by **finite-state-machine**.

Since I do not have a score of at least 5 on any of these tags, I am not able to perform tag synonyms. The fact that there are three (or even more) separate tags for finite-state-machines adds redundancy and makes searching harder.

Should these three tags be merged, using tag synonyms? If so, which one would be best-suited? (Considering the keywords "finite" and other StackOverflow-relevant meanings of the acronym fsm)

Comment: i'm not fond of acronym, but I prefer short tags, so [state-machine] would be a better candidate for me.

Comment: @Walfrat FSM is a very common term in HDL design, so eliminating that might not be a good idea. (My students are designing an FSM as I write - a module called fsm in a file called fsm.v). To be very pedantic (sorry), iFSM is an abbreviation, not an acronym.

Comment: Well, are we asking for finite state machine in HDL or in general ? Also the problem with acronyms is that you end up having more than one with the same.

Comment: There is also the `dfa` tag, which is also a kind of fsm. And `pda` (pushdown automaton).

Comment: "and other StackOverflow-relevant meanings of the acronym fsm" -- Stack Overflow-irrelevant meanings may be relevant too if they end up a distraction on SO. My first association with FSM is Flying Spaghetti Monster. I do not know if that's a common association.